# Apache not executing index.php as php code when accessed as the folder

Tags: php, apache

So on our website we have a folder, let's say its called `(webroot)/foo`

Inside this folder, there is a php file, `index.php`, that contains php code

When you go to `website.name/foo/index.php`, it works fine. However, when you just go to `website.name/foo/`, **the php code contained in the file is not executed, and remains plain text**. On some computers (but not others), **the file also gets downloaded for some reason.**

Note, I am not sure what files to show you, so tell me what files you need :) Also, I haven't really changed anything in any files.

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in the `foo` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` to a `.htaccess` of that directory but we should try to avoid using `.htaccess` and prefer `httpd.conf`

So check the conf file to make sure that `index.php` is present :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Restart apache2.

Matter slightly depends on server OS and what packages installed. Ubuntu needed one package more for PHP for proper functioning.